# $routeProvider is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have create a new project, but got a problem which I am not able to fix.

Here's my example:

```
angular.module('MosysTimes', ['ngRoute']).config($routeProvider, RouteConfiguration);

function RouteConfiguration ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'start.html',
            controller: 'WelcomeController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
```

It always says:

> $routeProvider is undefined....

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: What version? ngRoute is no longer part of the base library.

Comment: config expects an injectable function as unique argument. You're passing $routeProvider as argument, which is indeed not defined anywhere. Drop the first argument to config().

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to this.

```
angular.module('MosysTimes', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)
{
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'start.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    }); 
}]);
```

Comment: You should also explain the reason behind changing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add ngroute script to you index html?
for example:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

and try to use following syntax

```
angular.module("MosysTimes",['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'start.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('yourModule').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
  .when() .....
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$routeProvider` into function. After that you can use this `$routeProvider` to access the loading template on your main page.

Answer (score 0):

thanx to you all, after trying your hints I got it working and a bit of more understanding angular.. thx...